# Symfony: get a value in array

Tags: arrays, symfony, get

In symfony I have an array of entity with liaison:
$MyArray (id, name, array(product: id, name, price))
How to access at price for exemple ? .... $price = $MyArray->product->price ?

I want add items to an order and add some elements for exemple the price in the product data.

Comment: This question should be voided. If you are having problems working with basic [array](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) / [classes & objects](https://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.php) datatypes you should get down to more of the basics of PHP. Possibly by reading the documentation on the subjects or following some more detailed tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$prices = [];
foreach($MyArray->getProduct() as $product) {
  $prices[] = $product->getPrice()
}

dd($prices)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?